# How to get the video tag to work with fanxybox?

Tags: html, fancybox, html5-video

I want to play video's using the HTML5 `<video>` tag and fancybox, with the links directing to youtube videos?

here's my code so far

```
<video width="480" height="270" controls="controls" poster="../images/youtube-logo.png">
  <source src="http://o-o---preferred---sn-5hn7snl7---v12---lscache8.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=paJG2CcEhGw&amp;sparams=cp%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&amp;fexp=906356%2C910014%2C914093%2C922401%2C920704%2C912806%2C927201%2C922403%2C925003%2C913546%2C913556%2C916805%2C920201%2C901451&amp;ms=au&amp;expire=1352949266&amp;itag=46&amp;ipbits=8&amp;gcr=nl&amp;sver=3&amp;ratebypass=yes&amp;mt=1352923510&amp;ip=83.83.121.109&amp;mv=m&amp;source=youtube&amp;key=yt1&amp;cp=U0hUR1lPV19LUENONF9RSUFDOjBkVU41a1M4UEVp&amp;id=d72f1d6250563a1e&amp;signature=6C5130076CA770F67B4C797191BC0997EA040B74.10D3AEAA60E7AE1CF1D49DACF7178F3FCBBD56AE" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://o-o---preferred---sn-5hn7snl7---v12---lscache8.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=paJG2CcEhGw&amp;sparams=cp%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&amp;fexp=906356%2C910014%2C914093%2C922401%2C920704%2C912806%2C927201%2C922403%2C925003%2C913546%2C913556%2C916805%2C920201%2C901451&amp;ms=au&amp;expire=1352949266&amp;itag=46&amp;ipbits=8&amp;gcr=nl&amp;sver=3&amp;ratebypass=yes&amp;mt=1352923510&amp;ip=83.83.121.109&amp;mv=m&amp;source=youtube&amp;key=yt1&amp;cp=U0hUR1lPV19LUENONF9RSUFDOjBkVU41a1M4UEVp&amp;id=d72f1d6250563a1e&amp;signature=6C5130076CA770F67B4C797191BC0997EA040B74.10D3AEAA60E7AE1CF1D49DACF7178F3FCBBD56AE" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="http://o-o---preferred---sn-5hn7snl7---v12---lscache8.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=paJG2CcEhGw&amp;sparams=cp%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&amp;fexp=906356%2C910014%2C914093%2C922401%2C920704%2C912806%2C927201%2C922403%2C925003%2C913546%2C913556%2C916805%2C920201%2C901451&amp;ms=au&amp;expire=1352949266&amp;itag=46&amp;ipbits=8&amp;gcr=nl&amp;sver=3&amp;ratebypass=yes&amp;mt=1352923510&amp;ip=83.83.121.109&amp;mv=m&amp;source=youtube&amp;key=yt1&amp;cp=U0hUR1lPV19LUENONF9RSUFDOjBkVU41a1M4UEVp&amp;id=d72f1d6250563a1e&amp;signature=6C5130076CA770F67B4C797191BC0997EA040B74.10D3AEAA60E7AE1CF1D49DACF7178F3FCBBD56AE" type="video/webm">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
<iframe width="480" height="270" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/1y8dYlBWOh4?wmode=opaque">
</iframe>
</video>
```

As you can see i also added an `iframe` tag to support older browsers.

But after some tweaking i can't get fancybox to open everything, in any of the videos in the video tag??

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: it looks like your videos aren't accessible in the first place - you can't open them because they're not found

Comment: @ZoltanToth. They are a direct link to a Youtube video, i tested it under Firefox/chrome/opera. and it worked, the video played!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct YouTube links are 'refreshed', although they work for a moment the next day, they no longer work, cause the links are 'broken'.

the best way to play youtube videos in html5 is like so

```
<iframe width="480" height="270"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/1y8dYlBWOh4?html5=1">
</iframe>
```

the `html5=1` tells Youtube to use html5 to play the videos, and NOT flash!